# Handle browser back button with React router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

this is my first time here

I am working on a website that shows infos about movies and tv shows using TMDB API, React, Redux and React Router Dom.
I wanted to sort movies by genres and page. So in my Movies Page, i have a list of genres and each one of them has an ID which make my useEffect() hooks to rerender each time a new genre is clicked or the page is changed.

The link to the movies page looks like this **movies/:genreID/:pageNumber**. So basically, the idea was each time a genre is clicked or the page is changed, the url updates and i get the new genreID and pageNumber from it using useParams(), then i send them to dispatch and the component rerender.

My code looks like this

```js
const Movies = ({ isFrench, isOpen }) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const { genreID, pageNumber } = useParams();

  const language = isFrench ? "fr" : "";
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState(genreID);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(pageNumber);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMovies(language, page, genres));
    history.push(`movies/${genres}/${page}`);
  }, [dispatch, language, page, genres, history]);

  const { popularMovies, numOfPages, isLoading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.movies
  );

  //Change Category
  const changeCategoryHandler = (id) => {
    setPage(1);
    setGenres(id);
    getCategoryName(id);
  };

  //Print categories
  const frenchCategories = categoriesMoviesFR.map((category) => (
    <li onClick={() => changeCategoryHandler(category.id)} id={category.id}>
      {category.name}
    </li>
  ));
  
  ... 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that if i am on page 3 for example, and i press the browser's back button to return to page 2, I see that the link changes in the browser but the component is not updated. Same thing with the genres. If I quit Action for Adventure and hit the back button to go back to Action, I see the link changes but the component is not refreshed.

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of problem?
Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: can you also post your root file where you're importing the router provider and wrapping your app in it

Comment: Jesus i am having a hard time trying to add code in the comment, i am just going to add a new answer below

Comment: edit the question and add the code into it

Comment: The problem probably is you're storing genres and page using state, you expect it to change when there's the new value from the useParams(), but since the component is already mounted, useState(), instead of reinitializing with your new param values, keep the value that's in the state

Comment: You can console log values from useParams, and console the values in your state ( genre, page), this should make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  const { genreID, pageNumber } = useParams();
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState(genreID);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(pageNumber);
```

You are initialising your state with dynamic props value, but state's default value will never change, because useState is only called once. You can try printing out `genreID` and `pageNumber`, and `genres` & `page` to find out that.

**Solution**

You can directly use `{ genreID, pageNumber }` throughout your `Movies` component. If you really need to store them in state, use `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setGenres(genreID)
  setPage(pageNumber)
},[genreID, pageNumber])
```

I made a very simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-pitfall-fek4l) for you to have a clear vision on this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, the state was not updating !

But putting setGenres and setPage in useEffect() got me into a "Maximum update depth exceeded error".

I just checked their (tmdb) website, it seems like they too have problems with routing. Filtering movies by genres works but when you click on a movie to have more information then click on the back button, the filters disappear and you just land on the unfiltered movies page. 

Is there any different approach to make this work ?

Comment: To get rid of  "Maximum update depth exceeded error", you need to change `page, genres` in useEffect depencies to `genreID, pageNumber`. As for what you mentioned in tmdb website, they didn't register the filtered genre as a param in the url, so back button won't work. Alternatively, you can also store the filtered genre in a central state store, so you can reproduce the filtered results on `/movie` by checking your state, even without registering `/movie/:genre`

Comment: That's exactly what i have done and my url went crazy but it's okay, you helped me figure out a lot of things. I am going to try the redux store way.

Thanks for your help Janice and @Ashu. I am grateful

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So the index.js file looks like this

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```